# Grace period on Android in-app purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Android Market app purchases have a 15-min grace period when a customer can cancel a purchase for a full refund without vendor's involvement. Do in-app purchases have such a grace period, too? The docs are unclear on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no 15 min grace period, and there is no refund. You have to manually do it through your android publish account.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html
see the Handling Refunds section

Answer (score 1):

Google Checkout does not charge the card right away, though.